# Fitting a <ul>'s width to accommodate the menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have a menu that contains submenus. Its HTML source looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Item 1<a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">Subitem 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">Subsubitem 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

After applying some CSS and getting the JavaScript side of things in order with Superfish, the menu looks like this in the browser:

[image: The menu]

The second menu item is too big to fit into its space, so the remainder of the text is rendered onto the text of the next menu item. Is there a way to enlarge the `<ul>` to make sure that the text fits?

**Update**: here's the relevant CSS code:

```
ul#menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;
    left: 130px;
    width: 700px;
}
ul#menu, ul#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul#menu > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(img/menuitem.png) top left;
    width: 104px;
    height: 37px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#menu > li:hover {
    background-position: bottom left;
}
ul#menu > li > a {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
ul#menu > li > a, ul#menu > li > ul a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu > li ul {
    min-width: 150px;
}
ul#menu > li > ul li {
    color: black;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: url(img/menubg.png) repeat;
}
ul#menu > li > ul li:hover {
    background-color: #9c938c;
}
ul#menu > li > ul a {
    color: black;
}
ul#menu > li ul {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
ul#menu > li li.hoverItem > ul {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}
ul#menu > li > a > span.sf-sub-indicator {
    display: none;
}
ul#menu > li > ul > li a > span.sf-sub-indicator {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

`span.sf-sub-indicator` and `li.hoverItem` are used by Superfish. `sf-sub-indicator` is used to indicate that hovering over a menu item will cause a submenu to be opened like so:

```
<li>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="sf-with-ul">Menu item with submenu<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
  <ul>
    <!-- Etc -->
  </ul>
</li>
```

`li.hoverItem` is applied to all menu items you passed to get to the menu where your mouse is positioned, plus the menu item your mouse is currently hovering on.

Comment: Anything can happen "after applying some CSS". You should post CSS that affects LI.

Comment: Open to jQuery code, or just straight-up Javascript?

Comment: I already need jQuery on the same page, so if the jQuery solution is easier (very likely) I'd love to know. I'm making a WordPress theme so giving every `<li>` a unique number automatically will require additional research. If jQuery can work around that easily, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I put something together using the same css definitions that you posted above. This works for me - automatically detects the size of the largest element and adjusts the related CSS.

You'll need to adjust the li elements to have a predictable naming scheme, so that it can find the largest one. Depending on your font, you might need to adjust the `*5` portion of the assignment for the newSize.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeSize() {
  var html = document.getElementById("item"+1).innerHTML;
  var newSize = html.length*5;
  var num_menu_items = 3;
  for (i=2; i<=num_menu_items; i++) {
    var temp = document.getElementById("item"+i).innerHTML;
    if (temp.length > newSize / 5)
        newSize = temp.length*5;
  }
  var theRules = new Array();
  var rule;
  if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules)
    theRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
  else if (document.styleSheets[0].rules)
    theRules = document.styleSheets[0].rules
  for (i = 0; i<theRules.length; i++) {
    if (theRules[i].selectorText.indexOf("ul#menu > li ul") > -1) {
      rule = theRules[i];
    }
  }
  rule.style.setProperty('min-width',newSize+"px",null);
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload='changeSize();'>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>A-one</li>
  <li>A-two</li>
  <li>A-three
    <ul>
      <li id='item1'>B-one</li>
      <li id='item2'>B-two-is-really-really-really-really-really-really-really-really-really-really-really-really long</li>
      <li id='item3'>B-three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason I insist on having the CSS being adjusted automatically to fit the text is that I'm making a WordPress theme that shouldn't break with large page names.

Comment: Ok, I added code to do what you're looking for automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This block here:

```
ul#menu > li ul {
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

Is where the size for that item is. You will have to change that to something larger.
The reason it doesn't expand, is because its parent's width is small than that.