# Adjusting <ul>'s width to accommodate menu items using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml, menu

This is an expansion of a question I posted a while ago: [Fitting a <ul>'s width to accommodate the menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275997/fitting-a-uls-width-to-accommodate-the-menu-items)

Is there a snippet of jQuery code that can adjust the width of every `<ul>` inside a certain `<ul>` to make sure the `<li>` items don't overflow? The menu looks something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Item 1<a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">Subitem 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">Subsubitem 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If I don't adjust the `<ul>` correctly, the layout looks messed up as shown here:

[image: Site menu]

You can take a look at the site I'm developing [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101205014236/http://labs.pieterdedecker.be:80/vspwpg/?) if you need more information about the CSS or the general structure of the web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width problem actually stems from the width set at the top level here:

```
ul#menu > li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: url(img/menuitem.png) top left;
  width: 104px;                                 /* here's the issue */
  height: 36px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;                           /* add this */
}
```

Since it has a `width` specified, and its child is in the normal flow, its child is obeying *its* width, rather than scaling by itself.  What you can do is take the child out of the flow, by adding `position: realtive;` like I have in the above style, then give the child `<ul>` a `position: absolute`, like this:

```
ul#menu > li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;              /* top <li> is 36px, go down that much */
}
```

Then finally, so the anchor text gets a full background, give it a `white-space` rule like this:

```
ul#menu > li > a, ul#menu > li > ul a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here's what the result looks like:
[image]

Comment: Great solution, no Javascript involved.

Comment: @hitautodestruct this solution has a couple of bugs under ie6

Comment: I'm almost there, but there's something odd going on with my CSS. Have a look at this screenshot from Chrome's element inspector: http://a.imageshack.us/img6/6159/inspector.jpg

Comment: @Ignatz ie6 is dead. Supporting it is like caring for a corpse.
I don't understand what the problem is from the chrome screen shot.

Comment: @Pieter - Can you shoot me a link to the modified CSS to take a look? I'm still seeing the original on the site link in the question

Comment: I uploaded the modified CSS file to the site. Have you tried hitting CTRL+F5? Anyway, you can find the stylesheet here: http://www.pieterdedecker.be/labs/vspwpg/wp-content/themes/vspw/style.css

Comment: @hitautodestruct Chrome ignored certain CSS code, as visualized by those three CSS declarations that were struck out. The declarations that were effected are `display: block; text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: @Pieter - You're seeing that in the developer tools because  `ul#menu > li > a, ul#menu > li > ul a {` is repeated in your stylesheet, so the first definition of those styles are ignored, look at like 59 and line 89...apologies on the caching, that was my end, Chrome 6 dev version has messed up caching at the moment, even with Ctrl+F5.

Comment: @Pieter - Also the old styles for `ul#menu > li ul {` are at line 97, so they're overriding the corrected styles at line 72 :)

Comment: Oops, that makes total sense. Sheesh, I gotta stay focused when editing my CSS. But hey, thanks for solving my issue! The bounty is yours.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do (and the spacing should be consistent with your theme):

```
ul#menu > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
}
```

Comment: This is not the only issue, it would put the element at the top of the page, I've already addressed this fully in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `line-height` property from:

```
ul#menu > li > ul li {
  color:black;
  font-size:10pt;
   /*line-height:30px;*/
  text-align:left;
}
```

It displays fine or set the `line-height` to lesser value such as `20px`

Comment: I'd like all menu items to have the same height, so I'm afraid that this is not an option for me.

Comment: You can set the height like this then `$('ul#menu li').css('height', '20');` You can adjust the value.

Comment: But when the height is fixed (which is what I want), then it's possible for text to overflow. I'd like the width to be adjusted to fit the text onto one line, the height should remain the same.

Comment: `$('ul#menu li').css('width', '200');`

Comment: Try setting `width: auto;` and specify fixed height;

Comment: `width: auto` doesn't seem to change the situation. This doesn't prevent text from spilling over onto a new line instead of having the menu being resized to fit the text on one line. @Sarfraz: what if I'm dealing with text that requires more space than 200px?

Comment: @Pieter: Try setting the width in percents then rather than pixels.

Comment: That makes the `<li>` width relative to the underlying `<ul>`, if I remember my CSS theory correctly. That still doesn't ensure the menu is wide enough to fit every menu item on one line of text.